# How do you feature-gate trait derivation?

Tags: rust, traits

Lets say you got an enum like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
}
```

But you only want to derive, let's say `PartialEq`, if a certain feature (let's call it `myenum-partialeq`) is enabled.

How is this done idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`#[cfg_attr()]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "myenum-partialeq", derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
}
```

One thing that is nice to remember, is to always put `#[derive(Copy)]` on the same line or above `#[derive(Clone)]` if the struct is not generic. This is because if `#[derive(Clone)]` is on the same `#[derive()]` or below `#[derive(Copy)]` it expands to just performing a bitwise copy, while if it is above it performs a full-fledged `clone()` for each field, and that takes time and may not even be possible to optimize.

Comment: *About the derive note*: how weird... Usually, in Rust, the order of items / implementations / ... doesn't matter. Is it planned for `Clone` to be smarter about it?

Comment: @BlackBeans I think yes. The problem is that the compiler processes derives in order. This is not considererd a behavior change (although it can be observed), just an optimization.